# How to show WordPress search result of a predefined keyword in a static page

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am new to WordPress. I have an assignment for which I need your help. I need to create a static page in WordPress and include a search result with a predefined keyword(example 'Thermometer') in it with a custom template. I know how to create a page but don't know how to embed a search result in it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a page template with a search loop where you pass through your search query. You could include define your search value in your url if you wanted to. Then use the $_GET[] to pass in the value.

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Custom Search Page
*/
get_header();
$s = 'your search query';
$args = array(
    's' => $s
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    _e("<h2>Search Results for: ".get_query_var('s')."</h2>");
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       $the_query->the_post();
             ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
             <?php
    }
} else { ?>
    <h2>Nothing Found</h2>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
    </div>
<?php } 
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This works. This is exactly what I was looking for. With hardcoded query it worked fine.Just one more question,How do I use $_GET method. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: $_GET is how you get a url parameter.
For example: www.yourdomain.com/?search=your query
$_GET['search'] will hold the value 'your query'
So to pass it into the code, where you have 's' => 'your query' you can change it to 's' => $_GET['search'] 
Happy it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in various ways:

1. Show search results in an iframe
2. Make a custom page template file in your theme folder and add custom query to it, to make it show the search results of your query without being provided in the url